# Creating dynamic Response Assertion in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run tests on `JMeter` and I expect a certain format of text in response assertion but it can change dynamically depending on the request. The response that I am expecting is something similar to as shown below :

```
{
    "method": "<<Getting from the csv config file",
    "student_id": "<<getting from the csv config file>>",
    "term_id": "<<Getting from the csv Config file>>",
    "crns": [{
        "status_cd": "<<A numeric code from the response>>",
        "section": "<<N or Y from response>>",
        "message": "<<String value from response>>",
        "crn": "<<Getting from the csv config file>>"
    }]
}
```

I am not sure how to setup my response assertion to get the above format

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is better to use [JSON Path Assertion](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) for JSON data. It is available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project and can be installed in a couple of clicks using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JSON Path Extractor]

See [JSON Path - Getting Started](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#getting-started) and [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) to learn how to use JSON Path language for working with JSON data in JMeter